# Android run fails with message Failed to finalize session: INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY

Tags: android

I recently upgraded to gradle 3.4.1 on Android Studio 2.3.1. My build was working earlier. Anyway, the error I'm getting is:

[image]

I've wiped the data to the avd, made sure the app wasn't on it, restarted android studio and my mac, and made sure I didn't have the android:testOnly="true" flag set (I don't). I also added the flag and set it to false, but I still get the error.

Comment: What version of the Android gradle plugin are you using? I had this problem on 2.4.0-alpha4, but downgrading to 2.3.1 helped. (I also killed the Gradle daemon and restarted it)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem in Android Studio v2.3.1. 
I found stability when I set gradle version to 3.3 and android gradle plugin to 2.3.1. Stay off that bleeding edge gradle :)